# Find the value of $k$, $\int_k^2 \frac{1}{\ln(v)-v}\space\space dv = \int_1^e \frac{1}{x}\space\space dx=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It is given: $$x\frac{dv}{dx}=f(v)$$ and when $x=e$, $v=2$

If $k$ is the value of $v$ when $x=1$, $$\int_k^2 \frac{1}{f(y)}\space\space dy=1$$

Also:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln(y)-\ln(x)$$ and when $x=e$, $y=2e$

I am supposed to find the value of $k$:
$$\int_k^2 \frac{1}{\ln(v)-v}\space\space dv = \int_1^e \frac{1}{x}\space\space dx=1$$

Comment: It is easy to show by differentation that $k \mapsto \int_k^2 {\frac{{dv}}{{\log v - v}}}$ is a strcitly increasing function of the non-negative real variable $k$. For $k=2$ it is zero and it tends to infinity as $k\to +\infty$. Hence there is a unique $k$ that satisfies your requirement $\int_k^2 {\frac{{dv}}{{\log v - v}}}  = 1$. Numerically, $k=3.7864655704615870\ldots$. I doubt there is a simple expression for this number.

Comment: @Gary How did you get to that number?

Comment: Any reasonable software (e.g., Matlab, Mathematica, Maple etc.) can do it.

Comment: @Gary Oh, so it's not done by hand?

Comment: Of course not :)